# grails - how to force download file with its extension

Tags: java, grails, download

I have the following code

```
    def fileDoc = new File(document.documentLocation);
    if(fileDoc.exists()){
        // force download
        def fileName = fileDoc.getName();
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
        response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${fileName}" ;
        response.outputStream << fileDoc.newInputStream();
        response.outputStream.flush();
        return true;
   }
```

documentLocation contains string like "c:\mydoc\contains_some_long_string_with_id.pdf" for example.

I would like the user to download the file instead view it from browser. It works well on chrome where I could download and the file will be show up "save as" "contains_some_long_string_with_id.pdf"

but in firefox (latest one) .. the filename is crippled to "contains_some_long" only (without pdf extension at the end).

How to solve this problem ? the file could be csv,pdf, text, html, zip, pdf or other file format.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The content type string probably needs to bee the MIME type of the document you're downloading.

eg.  for PDF it should probably be "application/pdf"

Comment: but users can put any files with any format. it works well on chrome but on the firefox the filename will be crippled

Comment: Can your code check the file extension and set the correct file type at the time of download?  I think this may be the reason firefox is clobbering the extension.  I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have spaces or special characters that are confusing Firefox. The filename should be a quoted string:

```
response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${fileName}\"";
```

See [RFC 2616, section 19.5.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1).